# Flight PHP RESTful API not returning HTTP Status header

Tags: php, rest, flightphp

I am using the Flight PHP Framework to develop a RESTful API in PHP. Everything is working perfect except for all my routes the response from the API always contains the HTTP Status '200' even if I set it as '403' or '500' using the PHP code:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
```

I am using POSTMAN chrome add on to send calls to the API and it always returns status '200 OK'.

[image]

This is the FLIGHT PHP code:

```
Flight::route('GET /organisation/id', function(){

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_APIKEY']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENTID'])) {

    $organisationID = checkAPIKey($_SERVER['HTTP_APIKEY']);

    if ($organisationID !== false) {

        $response = array('status' => '200', 'data' => array('organisationID' => $organisationID));
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
        header('Content-type: application/json');

        logAPICall($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENTID'], $organisationID, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], json_encode($response), '', $_SERVER['HTTP_APIKEY']);

        echo json_encode($response);

    } else {

        header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $responseArray = array( 'status' => '403', 'errorCode' => '1', 'error' => 'Unauthorised API access');

        logAPICall($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENTID'], $organisationID, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], json_encode($responseArray), '', 'No API Key');

        $stmt = null;
        $db = null;

        echo json_encode($responseArray);

    }

} else {

    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $responseArray = array( 'status' => '403', 'errorCode' => '1', 'error' => 'Unauthorised API access or Missing Client Header');

    logAPICall('No Client Header', '', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], json_encode($responseArray), '', 'No API Key');

    $stmt = null;
    $db = null;

    echo json_encode($responseArray);

}
```

});

Any ideas as to why this is happening would be much appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't answer your question, but have you tried using the framework's json method? It works for me.

```
    Flight::json(array(
       'status' => 403,
       'errorCode' => '1'
    ), 403);
```

See [source](https://github.com/mikecao/flight/blob/master/flight/Engine.php#L468).